# Trying to get javascript variable to display within a sentence in HT

Tags: javascript, html, variables

Using javascript, I defined a variable as one of three words

http://jsfiddle.net/KDmwn/45/

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var things = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissor'];
var thing = things[Math.floor(Math.random()*things.length)];
});
```

I want the variable "thing" to display within a sentence on my screen  using the following in the HTML portion:

```
the computer chose <span id="thing></span>
```

If someone could help me figure out what's going wrong, I would appreciate it

Comment: What is going wrong is you dont have any code setting the content of your element, just creating a variable with same name as an element's id does not change the content of that element.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the HTML of the span. In your code you only created a variable, but you also need to use it somewhere in HTML. Since you are using jQuery you can use ID selector and `html()` method to set the value:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var things = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissor'];
    var thing = things[Math.floor(Math.random()*things.length)];
    $('#thing').html(thing);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It's still not working, though, even with setting the HTML of the span: http://jsfiddle.net/KDmwn/50/

Comment: Never mind! Realized that JQuery wasn't running in the JSFiddle. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Other than the already suggested

```
$('#thing').html(thing);
```

You can also use

```
$('#thing').append(thing);
```

or even

```
$('#thing').text(thing);
```

I guess it all depends on the bigger picture of your program. I am currently learning jQuery myself. It's really something.

[html](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

[append](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

[text](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Comment: Thanks for your help :) I tried using the .html(thing) and it still wouldn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/KDmwn/50/

Comment: Never mind! Realized that JQuery wasn't running in the JSFiddle. Thanks